# Accumulated sum of a pandas column, how calculate the subtraction

Tags: python, pandas, date, sum

So I have a dataframe with a column of cities, one numerical column (hospitalized), and a date column. I need to sum all the hospitalized according to date and the issue is that this hospitalized column gives me the accumulated number. Ex:

[image]

In this portion I have 1083 hospitalized on April 6th, and 1116 on April 7th, meaning 33 new patients were hospitalized.

The data starts on March, 2020 and I want to verify by date the total sum of new hospitalized patients, one line per day, let's say in the last 30 days for example.

Comment: Kindly post your data as text not as image so that we can reproduce your dataframe(also add your expected output if possible)

Comment: do you mean `groupby(date).sum(hospitalized)` ?

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).